# Pandas delete rows in a dataframe that are not in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've two pandas data frames which have some rows in common.

I want to identify the rows of df1 which are not in df2 (based on a condition like where df1.x = df2.x) and delete them from df1.

Also keeping everything unchanged in df2.

```
df1 = pandas.DataFrame(data = {'x' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'y' : [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]}) 
df2 = pandas.DataFrame(data = {'x' : [4, 5, 6], 'z' : [10, 13, 14]})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this:

```
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left', indicator='Exist')
df['Exist'] = np.where(df.Exist == 'both', True, False)
df = df[df['Exist']==True].drop(['Exist','z'], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 6):

IIUC:

```
df1 = df1[df1['x'].isin(df2['x'])]
```

---

```
df1
    x   y
3   4   13
4   5   14
```

Comment: Short and easy to understand! Note that you can easily change it to include only entries which are _not_ in df2 (which is why I found the page :-) ):  
  
`df1 = df1[~df1['x'].isin(df2['x'])]`

Answer (score 0):

```
    df1 = pandas.DataFrame(data={'x': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'y': [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]})
    df2 = pandas.DataFrame(data={'x': [4, 5, 6], 'z': [10, 13, 14]})
    #create blank dataframe to store values that are present in both:
    df3 = pandas.DataFrame()
    #check 'x' column of each row of each dataframe to find matches:
    for i in range (len(df1)):
        for ii in range(len(df2)):
            if df1.iloc[i]['x'] == df2.iloc[ii]['x']:
                #if there's a match, append it to df3:
                df3 = df3.append(df1.iloc[i])
    #delete df3 from df1 and rename it as df1:
    df1 = pandas.concat([df1,df3]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)
    print(df1)
```

output:

```
     x     y
0  1.0  10.0
1  2.0  11.0
2  3.0  12.0
```

Comment: Hi, Marina! While this solution works, is always better to use pandas functions to do the same thing than pure python code, given that Pandas functions run in C at low level and it is more performant than a python for comparison.

Comment: @Natacha thank you for the feedback! I'll keep in mind for future :)